# Scala: what does _ represent in this case

Tags: scala, lifting

I'm reading a tutorial for demonstration about lifting method in Scala. Here is the code for basic class:

```
case object None extends Optional[Nothing]

case class Presenter[+A](get: A) extends Optional[A]

trait Optional[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Optional[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Presenter(x) => Presenter(f(x))
  }
}
```

Here is the lift method:

```
  def lift[A, B](f: A => B): Optional[A] => Optional[B] = _ map f
```

My question is: what does underscore ("_") represent in above function.

thanks

Comment: lift returns a new function from Optional[A] to Optional[B]. So Optional[A] is the input argument of this new function.
So in this case, the _ represents the argument Optional[A] on which the 'map' function is called with the 'f' argument of the 'lift' function.

Answer (score 2):

`_ map f` is equal to `(a: Optional[A]) => a.map(f)`, `_` is wildcard in **Scala**. for your example, it means for parameter with type `Optional[A]` and apply to `map f`

Comment: thanks. can you tell me what rule in scala for us to know what _ mapping to

Comment: The marked duplicate answer is better for you. :)